# Implementing relationship databases scheme

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

Hey I have to create database's which should be like scheme below: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH1ZB.jpg

but without 'contact' table. Is this even possible?

And another question: 
How to put few values into single field? Is it possible, or I need to create extra table?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGRtq.jpg

Comment: You can certainly create a database consisting of the other 4 tables, but without the `contact` table it will be of limited usefulness.

Comment: DO NOT put multiple values into a single tuple. This violates 1NF and is unbelievably painful to work with. When you encounter the desired to do this it is a clear sign you need a table for that information.

Comment: So my concept is quite reasonable? Is not a problem that 'contact' table contains only one field?

Comment: What do you think about this concept?
http://imgur.com/a/L7uIu

Comment: Please make everything that can be text text. Like your schema and example tables (use code format to align columns).  Do not rely on images.

Comment: "How to put few values into single field?" is unintelligible.

Comment: As to your original question: So a contact can span multiple companies plus multiple employees (that are not related to a particular company) plus multiple emails (that are neither related to a particular employee nor to a particular company) plus multiple phone numbers (again not related to any of the other entities). What can this be good for?

Comment: As to your other database: company_has_emails? This is a table allowing the same email used by many companies (it's an n:m bridge table). Shouldn't one email belong to exactly one company? Same for phones and maybe for employees, too. What you probably need instead is a phones table with a column specifying the related employee and an email table with a column specifying the related employee and an employee table with a column specifying the department they work for and a department table with a column specifying the company it resides in. Something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to model this without the Contact table.
A solution could be to put the Employee table in the center of de model. Then you could link the Phone_number and Email_address tables to the Employee table with a one-to-many relationship, just like they are modeled currently to Contact. Since a Employee could have multiple email adresses and multiple phone numbers, those tables should have a foreign key of Employee.

The only thing you have to keep in mind is the cardinality of the relationship of the Employee table to the Company table. To eliminate data redundancy, you might want to have a many-to-many relationship there, since an Employee could have multiple Employers and a Company could belong to multiple Employees. This means that you will end up having a junction table.

Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your design diagram according to the usual interpretation of crow's feet for foreign keys, every company, employee, email address and phone number has exactly one contact and every contact has at least one of each of those. So the set of ids in Contact is always the union of the sets of contact ids in the other four tables. So you don't need Contact. (But if instead a contact could exist without being associated with any of the other four entities then the four tables alone wouldn't be able to record those business situations.)

I guess by the unclear "How to put few values into single field?" you mean how do you put multiple values into one field. Pick a function that maps the multiple values to a single value in a way that you can undo/invert. But if you are ever interested in querying using the individual values then you should not do this, it is a bad design. Research it. (This is often said to violate 1NF, but that depends on what is meant by 1NF, a term used to mean a lot of different things. Ultimately in cases where it can be said to violate it, 1NF itself depends on what part of values you want to be able to query.)